# WPF event property changed?

Tags: .net, wpf

What interface must i implement to be able to create wpf event when some thing changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

INotifyPropertyChanged.

It's in [System.ComponentModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

A small trick when using this interface, when you implement it with an empty delegate you don't have to check if the event is null every time you raise it.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
```

Answer (score 4):

WPF controls inherit DependencyObject class. See: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx)

For business entities, you could still implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 4):

[INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).  Here is a "[How To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx)".