# How to accomplish two-way data binding in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, two-way-binding

I have heard a lot about two-way bindings in WPF, but I'm not entirely clear on how to accomplish it or what it actually means.

I have a `ListView` with a bunch of items in it. When the user selects a new item, a `TextBox` in the application will change its text to display some property of the selected item.

But when the user changes the text in the text box I want the `ListView` item to be updated immediately as well. Is there any "two-way binding" magical WPF way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you haven't you'll need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your class that you're binding to.

Also, when you say you want the `ListBox` item to be updated immediately, you mean that you want it to change as you type in the `TextBox`.  By default the `TextBox.Text` property updates its source when it loses focus, but you can change this by setting the binding `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`:

```
{Binding Source={...}, Path=Whatever, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

Comment: Depending on how he has things set up, that Source may need to be changed to ElementName (with a Path of SelectedItem.Whatever), or, if the set of bound items is the DataContext, can be omitted, but in the latter case the ListView will need IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True".

Comment: It's just like itowlson says. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 34):

[Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180221/wpf-two-way-binding/2180263#2180263) shows how to accomplish what you want, but you also asked more generally about "how to accomplish [two-way binding] and what it actually means."

One-way binding means that the binding target (e.g. control) will display data from the binding source (e.g. business object), and will update itself as the business object changes, but that changes to the control will not be propagated back to the business object.  E.g. if the Person.Name changes from "bob" to "kate", the TextBlock.Text bound to the Name will change from "bob" to "kate" too.

Two-way binding simply means that not only are changes in the business object reflected in the UI, but changes made by the user in the UI are propagated back to the business object too.  So now when the user edits the TextBox.Text bound to the Name, say changing "kate" to "edmund", WPF will set the Person.Name property to "edmund" as well.

To accomplish this, just set Mode=TwoWay on the Binding declaration.  Some properties bind two-way by default: TextBox.Text, for example, binds TwoWay by default, which is why Mark's code doesn't need the Mode declaration.  In addition, as Mark notes, by default WPF only propagates changes back to the business object when the control loses focus.  If you have two UI elements bound to the same property, this can mean they appear out of sync, in which case you can use the UpdateSourceTrigger to force WPF to propagate whenever the property changes.

MSDN covers this in detail with some good clear diagrams: see [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx) in the WPF SDK.

Comment: Up voted. Went through a ton of search results that all described how to implement two-way data binding, but none that explained the concept.  Your post did and quite succinctly.

Comment: Thanks for this, especially the statement "Some properties bind two-way by default: TextBox.Text, for example, binds TwoWay by default" This helped enormously :)

Comment: Sadly, this article is no longer available.  I'm not sure if there's an equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

What is the Type of the items in the `ListView`? To get the two way binding going the need you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`...

This might help [WPF event property changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626613/wpf-event-property-changed)

Comment: The items in the list view are objects that do implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.